# Remove all string between two strings

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to ask if it's possible to delete all strings between two strings even on different line ?

Here is the original file:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.0.32',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/files/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://192.168.0.44/files',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'dbport' => '',
  'installed' => true,
  'loglevel' => 2,
  'maintenance' => false,
);
```

What I expect :

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (

  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/files/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://192.168.0.44/files',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'dbport' => '',
  'installed' => true,
  'loglevel' => 2,
  'maintenance' => false,
);
```

I want to empty everything inside trusted domains.

What I tried :

```
sed -e 's/\(trusted_domains\).*\(\),\)/\1\2/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `sed` operates only line by line. There are some commands and options using which you can operate on multiple lines. For example, if your `sed` supports `-z` option and input doesn't contain the ASCII NUL character, you can do this:

```
$ sed -zE 's/(trusted_domains[^(]+\()[^)]+/\1/' ip.txt
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/files/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://192.168.0.44/files',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'dbport' => '',
  'installed' => true,
  'loglevel' => 2,
  'maintenance' => false,
);
```

This will slurp entire input content and `sed` would see only one input record. So, this will not be suitable for large input files. Also, here it is assumed that parenthesis are not part of contents of `array`

Perl has an option to slurp entire input content irrespective of characters present:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/trusted_domains[^(]+\(\K[^)]+//' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier using `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(trusted_domains.*=>\s*array\s*\()[\s\S]*\),/$1\n  ),/' file.php
```

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/files/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://192.168.0.44/files',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'dbport' => '',
  'installed' => true,
  'loglevel' => 2,
  'maintenance' => false,
);
```